# How to delete specific rows from a csv?

Tags: python, csv

I have a little problem in my csv and it is that I want to remove these commas below so that when you want to write something in append mode again, they will be written below the letters because if the commas are there and what you write will be written below the commas.

The content of my csv is this:

```
PRODUCTS, BRANDS, PRICES,
Doritos, Barcel, $ 13,
Iphone 12, Apple, $ 26,899,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
```

I just want to remove the commas below and not the above, as the instruction would be.

Comment: Copy the file and skip the rows with commas.

Comment: Like DataDruid said: this often happens when you generate a .csv with blank lines or empty rows at the bottom: the trailing spaces get saved as separate entities.  MAIN SUGGESTION: Fix your .csv generator, if possible.  Otherwise, do as martineau said: copy the file, then skip rows with commas.